# SQL trigger that dissolves feature class based on multilabel fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, dissolve, trigger

I am about write an SQL trigger which dissolves a feature class based on 5 fields, I used to do this using dissolve tool in the Arcmap as the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Now, I need this process to be automated, so when the user inserts or updates the SDE database the trigger should be able to dissolve the feature class based on the above criteria.

How can I start with this job, I used to write simple SQL triggers however that isn't sufficient to fulfill this process.

Comment: This really doesn't make any sense. A trigger is linked to an insert, update, or delete event. A 'dissolve' stored procedure almost makes sense, but not if you have `arcpy` available.

Comment: Thanks Vice, your right about the  "insert, update, or delete event", but I used to update the F.C by inserting new polygons and sometimes delete , and yes I have arcpy